# launch Android application's actions within another application

Tags: android, launcher, installed-applications

And I wonder if is possible to open an specific action I mean for example open a new mail in the gmail application, or new message on whatsapp stuff like that.

I'm trying to lunch application's specific actions within my application, so it interacts with a couple of more applications.

if is possible how to achieve that.

so far I do can lunch the application with the package name.

or get the package list from getInstalledPackages but I cant find that there be published the application actions.

is that dependent on the application ?

as well I know that I can do something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
```

to prompt the user for a selection (if not default) for that action. but I cant find related information to lunch the app skiping the users input.

I hope this be possible at least for the most popular applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getInstalledPackages` almost contains all you can get from PackageManager about an application. But it doesn't contain the intents of each components. In particular, ActivityInfo doesn't contain a field to store the intent or action to start it. As far as I know, it is difficult to get what you want programatically.

But for popular application, you can directly have their apks, get their `AndroidManifest.xml` and get what you want manually.

If you want to skip the user input if multiple components(applications) can handle your action, then you need to specify the component explicitly by `intent.setComponent()`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_NAME);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.TargetActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is right, I've to get the manifest and from there get the intents at least the filter that are the "common"